# send multi object in response by expressjs

Tags: json, node.js, express, response

I have a simple middleware in expressjs

```
app.get("/" , function(req , resp , next){

/* object 1 with data */
var obj1 = [ 
             {"name":"linda","family":"kamelia"},
             {"name":"ama","family":"kandi"},
             {"name":"lucy","family":"lofa"}
           ];

 /* object 2 with data */
 var obj2 = [ 
             {"name":"kama","family":"kambril"},
             {"name":"soli","family":"sepani"},
             {"name":"sara","family":"fani"}
           ];

    resp.send("First: " + obj1 + "<br> Secoud: " + obj2 );
});
```

it show me this result in output:

```
First: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
Secoud: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

how can I print the real data from response in output?

Answer (score 1):

That not gonna work in this format try this

```
resp.send({First: obj1 ,Secoud:  obj2});
```

Now you will get the object with two properties `First and Second` and access it with `obj.First and obj.Second`

Comment: Alternatively you can use two-dimensional array and do `resp.send([obj1, obj2])`

Answer (score 0):

Stringify the object

```
resp.send("First: " + JSON.stringify(obj1) + "<br> Secoud: " + JSON.stringify(obj2) );
```

Answer (score 0):

See,

First of all instead of using `res.send()` use `res.json()`.

Then, improve it by sending like this:

`res.json({"obj1":JSON.Stringify(obj1), "obj2":JSON.Stringify(obj2)});`

else you can try as well

`res.json({"obj1":obj1, "obj2":obj2});`

and on client end you can recieve it like this :

`var data = JSON.Stringify(result); 
var obj1 = data[0].obj1 && var obj2 = data[0].obj2`

Answer (score 0):

You can send them separately,
like :

```
res.write(obj1);
res.write(obj2);
res.end();
```

**Note:** `res.send()` functions calls `end()` functions by default